# read audio file without playing it

Tags: iphone, audio, itunes

I need to somehow read an audio file from iTunes for the iPhone app I am writing, without playing the file. I want to read the content of the file to examine various attributes of it without playing it - I know how to play it(Apple has loads of documentation of this). I haven't dealt with audio files at all in the past, and can't even seem to find a starting place. If anyone can give me a starting point - not even necessarily iOS specific, that would be great.

Comment: What file format? MP3, CAF, WAV, AIFF?  What attributes are you after?

Comment: Well I want to do be able to support any file iTunes supports, so Audio formats supported: AAC, MP3, Audible, Apple Lossless, AIFF, and WAV... I would like to detect the bpm of the song in the file.

Answer (score 1):

`AudioFile` and `ExtAudioFile` APIs (AudioToolbox.framework) are some ways to access the files' data - sample data and properties.

Answer (score 1):

Look into Apple's AVAssetReader Framework API and sample code.